# Open redirect page in new tab and reopen in the same tab on multiple redirects Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, redirect, tabs

I am making a blog app in Django and I want to do the following things

1. When the user submits the preview button I want to open the partially completed blog in a new tab in the same window.
2. Secondly if the user does not close the tab and again presses preview button, I want to display the updated blog in the tab which was previously opened.

How can I do this?

**Edit:**
As told in the answer below I am trying to use this code snippet to open it in a new window, but this does not work

```
<script>
    var current_link = $(location).attr('href');
    $('.preview_button').onClick(function() {
        window.open(current_link,'preview_tab');
    });
</script>
```

Also I currently have 3 submit buttons and I want to provide this feature only for 1 submit button i.e. **preview** So I cannot directly do `(#form).onSubmit`. For the the other two buttons, one updates the content via Ajax and the other redirects to a new page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a Javascript `onSubmit` to open the appropriate preview page with [`window.open`](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/openinga.htm), passing a name as the second parameter. It does almost exactly that. (If you want to support having different preview tabs associated with different editing tabs, include something in the name based on a tab ID of some kind -- maybe the article ID plus a random number, or something.)

You'll have to also send the updated content into the server via AJAX.

Comment: Since I am working in Django, I do not have a direct access to the url, since that is handled by the view. So what should I pass in the url??? The current link itself because my form submits to that page only

Comment: Use the `{% url %}` tag in the template: something like `<form onsubmit="ajaxSubmit(); window.open('{% url the-preview-page and then its arguments %}', 'my-site-awesome-preview'); return false" action='.' method='POST'>`. You'll have to write the `ajaxSubmit()` function to actually send in the form values, of course.

Comment: But the problem is that there are two more buttons in addition to this one. Your onsubmit will be fired when either of the three buttons are clicked. Whereas I just want to do preview button

Comment: What doesn't work about your code above? If it's submitting the form, you may need to use preventDefault().

Comment: No what I meant is that there are two submit buttons and I want to associate this action with only one of those buttons. However using onSubmit this script will be fired when any of the submit buttons is clicked

Comment: Right -- but your code snippet above uses onClick. Which that and preventDefault() I think it should work....

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at it